# How to stop event Enter keyCode (13), then execute tab keyCode(9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, event-handling, keyboard-events

I have a combobox, when input data, combobox search data then klick or press down arrow then enter / tab to choose that option, Enter keyCode(13) just working in combobox if the data focus but Tab keyCode(9) working / choose option without focus, but I can't find how to focus in combobox

this is my combobox code :

```
$('#ManifestDetail'+i+'AwbNumber').combobox({});
```

this is my html form code :

```
<select id="ManifestDetail0AwbNumber" onchange="completeData(0)" name="data[ManifestDetail][0][awb_number]" style="display: none;"> <option value="">-- Select Awb --</option> <option value="209468">0164914</option> <option value="209461">0164931</option> </select><input class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
```

if possible, can i set autofocus in combobox jQuery in my code ?.. if isn't how can I set enter keyCode(13) to tab keyCode(9), so when I press enter jQuery execute tab keyCode(9).

I already try with this code :

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').keypress(function(e){
                if (e.keyCode == 13){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var ne = new jQuery.Event("keyup");
                    ne.which = 9;
                    $(e.target).trigger(ne);
                }
            });
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just focus combobox directly?

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').keypress(function(e){
     if (e.keyCode == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('yourComboBoxSelector').next().find('input').focus();
     }
});
```

Comment: I have tried to using .trigger('focus'), but because preventDefault(), nothing happen

Comment: e.preventDefault(); just disable default behaviour of keypress event here, can you show us the html, not sure what element must be focus

Comment: <select id="ManifestDetail0AwbNumber" onchange="completeData(0)" name="data[ManifestDetail][0][awb_number]" style="display: none;">
<option value="">-- Select Awb --</option>
<option value="209468">0164914</option>
<option value="209461">0164931</option>
</select><input class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">

Comment: :( not working, what's wrong with my code, $('yourComboBoxSelector') meaning $('#ManifestDetail'+i+'AwbNumber') right ?

Comment: yeah, but for your test do $('#ManifestDetail0AwbNumber') direcly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120091/discussion-between-onesinus-saut-and-gatsbill).